# Can someone explain what´s happend in this codesnippet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I´m working with ASP.NET MVC and went through some code and the syntax below is new for me. Could someone explain me how it works?

```
ViewDataInfo vdi = viewData.GetViewDataInfo(expression);
Func<object> modelAccessor = null;

modelAccessor = () => vdi.Value;
```

Comment: Which part are you asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ViewDataInfo vdi = viewData.GetViewDataInfo(expression);
```

Getting the result of the `GetViewDataInfo` method, called with parameter `expression`.

```
Func<object> modelAccessor = null;
modelAccessor = () => vdi.Value;
```

Creating and initializing the delegate (function pointer) in view of *lambda function*. When in future code you make a call `modelAccessor()`, it'll return `vdi.Value`.

`()` - this means the function retrieve no parameters.
`Func<object>` - the function will return an `object`.
`vdi.Value` - is the short variant of `{ return vdi.Value; }`

[Read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) about the lambda-functions.

Answer (score 1):

This line sets the `ViewDataInfo` to the `vdi` variable:

```
ViewDataInfo vdi = viewData.GetViewDataInfo(expression);
```

This line initializes a null [`Func<object>` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) variable:

```
Func<object> modelAccessor = null;
```

This line sets the `Func` to a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that returns the value of `vdi`:

```
modelAccessor = () => vdi.Value;
```

Where the code below stands for an [anonymous function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx) that takes no parameter and returns an `object` (as specified in the generic type of the `Func` declaration):

```
() => vdi.Value
```